# What is the easiest way to run a single NodeJS script using Docker and be able to terminate it with Ctrl-C

Tags: node.js, docker

Taken from Docker's documentation that if you want to run a standalone NodeJS script you are supposed to use the following command:

`docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node:8 node your-daemon-or-script.js`

This works except that it's not possible to stop the script using Ctrl-C. How can I achieve that?

Here is my script.js:

```
console.log('Started - now try to kill me...');

setTimeout(function () {
   console.log('End of life.');
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This note is hidden in the [extended `docker run` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#foreground):

> **Note:** A process running as PID 1 inside a container is treated specially by Linux: it ignores any signal with the default action. So, the process will not terminate on `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM` unless it is coded to do so.

The main Docker container process (your container's `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` or the equivalent specified on the command line) runs as process ID 1 inside the container.  This is normally reserved for a special init process and is special in a couple of ways.

Possibly the simplest answer is to let Docker inject an init process for you as PID 1 by adding `--init` to your `docker run` command.

Alternatively, on Node you can register a [signal event](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_signal_events) to explicitly handle `SIGINT`.  For example, if I extend your script to have

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    process.exit();
});
```

and then rebuild the image and re-run it, it responds to ^C.

Comment: Thanks, accepted as an answer since both suggestions work! Is there any disadvantage of using the --init parameter in the docker run command as this seems the most elegant way since it doesn't require injecting any code into the NodeJS sources?

Comment: If having the absolute tiniest runtime profile is important to you, `--init` adds another process, but the particular init Docker injects here (tini) is pretty small.  There's a matching Docker Compose option, but if you step out of plain-Docker land, I'm pretty sure there's no corresponding option in a Kubernetes Pod, for example.